# Yii2 MongoDB query with condition or

Tags: mongodb, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Using MongoDB on Yii2 I'm trying to get all rows from table that contain a value I'm looking for using query find with where and or but my query return a blank page but in my table there are 2 rows minimum that contain the value I'm searching for

```
$model = Querytest::find()->where(
                         ['or', 
                         ['like', 'title', '%' . $key . '%', false] , 
                         ['like', 'keyword', '%' . $key . '%', false]
                         ])
                ->all();
 return $model;
```

I did a try with :

```
$model = Querytest::find()->where(
                         ['$or', 
                         ['like', 'title', '%' . $key . '%', false] , 
                         ['like', 'keyword', '%' . $key . '%', false]
                         ])
                ->all();
 return $model;
```

But I get error message say : Illegal offset type

Comment: Have you tried changing `['like', 'title', '%' . $key . '%', false]` to `['like', 'title', $key]`? I haven't used Yii with MongoDB, but `%` is not a wildcard there, Yii maybe converting your query to something like `db.queryTest.find({title: /key/})`.

Comment: Yes it's working You are genius